# Vue.js is routing javascript file as index page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have several JavaScript files that I want to include globally in my web page.

In `index.html`, I include the script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/my-file.js"></script>
```

In the console, it gives the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

When I visit the URL directly at http://localhost:8080/js/my-file.js, it shows the `index.html` page as the content instead of the JavaScript file's content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>main-interface-2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my-file.js"></script>
  <link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but main-interface-2 doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I think this might be because I either have the path wrong, or the Vue router is routing the JavaScript page when it shouldn't be.

How can I globally include regular JavaScript files into my Vue project since they aren't `npm` packages that utilize `export` and depend on being globally included in the head in order to function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `Unexpected token '<'`

It sounds like your JavaScript file doesn't exist at the specified URL, so the Webpack dev server is falling back to `public/index.html`, causing the `<script>` tag to fail parsing the HTML as JavaScript.

As a troubleshooting step (allowing you to see the `404` more clearly), you can [configure your project](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) to disable the dev server fallback with [`devServer.historyApiFallback=false`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback):

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: false
  }
}
```

#### Static assets

Copy your static JavaScript files to a location under the [`public` folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder), so that they're automatically bundled:

```js
<projectRoot>/public/js/my-file.js
```

Then you could use it in `public/index.html` like this:

```html
<script src="/js/my-file.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the script tag to your `app.vue` :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <script defer src="https://address/to/myscript.js"></script>
  </div>
<template>
```

Even can add it to head like this:

```
mounted() {
      let script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src =  "https://address/to/myscript.js";
      document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Script tags are ignored in the template